# MySQL - Count column less than other column in same table

Tags: mysql, count

i want to COUNT column less than with other column which if Quantity in Hand < Minimum Quantity and i should get the result = 5

Instead, i got the result = 3.

| stock_id | stock_qtyhand | stock_minQty |

|       1           |           60            |         100        |

|       2       |           29            |          58         |

|       3       |           12            |          20         |

|       4       |            5             |          35         |

|       5       |           30            |          67         |

What seems to be the problem?

```
rsLowStock.Open "SELECT COUNT(stock_id) AS LowStock FROM stock_general WHERE stock_qtyhand<stock_minQty",conn
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: What does your data look like? How do you know you should be getting 5 instead of 3?

Comment: @AndrewArnold i updated how's my data looks like. Sorry about that.

Comment: I get the expected `5` using your data and query. Double check that you are using the right database. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35db0f/2

Comment: SOLVED!!! The problem is im using VARCHAR for all those column. I changed it to double / int and it works. Thanks guys!